# Deriving function parameter types from another function

Tags: typescript

Given the following Typescript declarations:

```
interface Options {
  debug?: boolean;
}

declare function copy(text: string, options?: Options): boolean;
```

and the following typed identifier:

```
const copyFn as copy
```

I know I can "copy" the parameter types to an additional function using the `Parameters` utility type, like this:

```
const copy2 = (
    text: Parameters<typeof copy>[0], 
    options: Parameters<typeof copy>[1])
) => { }
```

repeating `Parameters<typeof copy>` twice.

**How can I express a function type that has precisely the same parameters as a different function type?**

Comment: Does `copy2 = (...args: Parameters<typeof copy>) => {}` work?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, that works. Except that I can't refer to `text` or `options` within the body of the function; I have to use `args[0]` and `args[1]`.

Comment: You can deatruct it `const [text, options]  = atfs`

Comment: @wonderflame Within the body of the function. Can I deconstruct it in the function signature?

Comment: Sure, `declare function copy2(...[text, options]: Parameters<typeof copy>) {}`. Should I write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mentioning each argument manually just spread the arguments in on array argument and destruct it how you need:

```
declare function copy2(...[text, options]: Parameters<typeof copy>) {}
```